# How to import pygame.locals successfully

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Hello there Stackoverflowers,

I am learning how to program with Pygame and I am trying to import pygame.locals
According to the tutorial I am learning from, I am starting of as such;

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *
```

I get this error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:/Python33/test.py", line 2, in  from pygame.locals import * ImportError: No module named 'pygame.locals'

I have downloaded Pygame (binary package) for Python 3.2, and I am currently running 3.3.
When I `import pygame` in the Python shell, no error is returned, and thus I am lead to believe that Pygame was successfully installed. 
I am running Windows 7 64 Bit.

I've seen a similar post regarding pygame.locals and Raspberry Pi and Linux, so I think this post is still relevant. Let me know if it is not.

Comment: Do you encounter some sort of an error when importing `pygame.locals`? What does it say?

Comment: I am returned with
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python33/test.py", line 2, in <module>
    from pygame.locals import *
ImportError: No module named 'pygame.locals'`

Comment: When you enter `from pygame.locals import *` in python shell, are you get error?

Comment: Can you enter `import pygame; print(pygame.__file__)` in python shell and paste output of it?

Comment: First returned error is 

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    from pygame.locals import *
ImportError: No module named 'pygame.locals'`


Second is `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    import pygame; print(pygame.__file__)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__file__'`

Comment: Remove old `pygame` and then download `pygame-1.9.2a0.win-amd64-py3.3.exe` from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame), and install it, now i think it should works.

Answer (score 14):

My guess is that you have a file named pygame.py in the current directory in which you are running you script.

Comment: I downloaded Pygame once and it did not work, so I redownloaded it and it works now (minus pygame.locals, of course, and perhaps some other things I am yet unaware of).

When I go to python33 (my Python 3.x folder) I have a pygame subfolder within Lib. Within Pygame, I have 'pycache', and within that only '__init__.cpython-33'.

Answer (score 0):

I found that on Windows 7 64-bit, you need to get [Python 3.3.5](http://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.3.5/python-3.3.5.msi), as well as the pygame-1.9.2a0-hg version [from Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame/downloads/pygame-1.9.2a0-hg_56e0eadfc267.win32-py3.3.msi).

This solved the problem `ImportError: No module named 'pygame.locals'` for me.

(Somehow it's a bit weird that the pygame website doesn't provide latest versions of pygame.)

Answer (score 0):

yes @Bartlomiej Lewandowski, you were right.I also faced the same problem and came here to resolve it. I did not download any newer version as apt-get install was giving the message that this is the newest version.

I just renamed my file pygame.py to some other random name.
It is working fine now. **So the problem was we named our file as pygame.py, Which is restricted in pygame module**, I am not sure. But its working fine now.

Thanks Bartlomiej Lewandowski once again.

Answer (score 0):

For RedHat I needed to install
yum install SDL-devel-1.2.14-7.el6_7.1.x86_64

Comment: This seems off-topic as OP never specified they were using RedHat to begin with...