# from pygame.locals import * doesn't work

Tags: python, pygame

I am new to python and want to make a game in pygame. I have looked online and everyone says do this first:

```
import pygame 
from pygame.locals import *
```

However, the shell window says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...", line 2, in <module>
   from pygame.locals import *
ImportError: No module named 'pygame.locals'
```

I am new so I have no idea why this works for others. Maybe I haven't installed something. Please tell me what. I am using python 3.4.0 and it is on a Ubuntu computer 14.04.

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import pygame.locals successfully](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21062062/how-to-import-pygame-locals-successfully)

Comment: Looking at related, it looks like you're not the only one having this issue, but I didn't see any actual accepted answer to mark this as a dupe.  Just to make sure (since this was brought up a couple of times): you don't have a file called pygame.py in your directory?

Answer (score 1):

Saw something similar to this, hope this helps

Your problem is that in that that current directory you have a file names `pygame.py`, or a bytocode left-over from such a file named `pygame.pyc`.

Meaning when you call pygame it will work but never actually import pygame, but the pygame file you have left. And since your file can't find a module named `locals` in that file, the error is raised.

So, just rename your file to anything other than `pygame.py` or other names of modules you want to import, or if you do have a `pygame.pyc` bytecode file, remove that.

Comment: give me an example because I used myfirstgame.py and that didn't work. Why?

Comment: Look for any files named pygame.pyc in your directory, if they is any change their names.

Comment: I checked but everything has a name and the ending ".py". for example I have something like tests.py or ghost.py but nothing as pygame because this is my first time using it. Also it could be I haven't fully installed it?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same situation, and essentially C. McCarthy is right. First you need to rename any files in the working directory called 'pygame.something'. Then you need to remove any remaining files named 'pygame.something' from your working directory. (Alternatively you could also move to another, fresh directory and try there.)

If you think you HAVE removed everything then you should also check for pygame.pyc and pygame.py~ (maybe others as well, but these were the ones I had) both of which are hidden and won't turn up under normal conditions.

To look for these you can type into the terminal (whilst in the directory in question):

```
ls pygame.*
```

which will show all the filenames that contain 'pygame.' . If there are any, you can remove them with,

```
rm pygame.*
```

This all worked for me, and I am running Ubuntu 14.04