# python doesn't find pygame.locals

Tags: python, pygame

I have sucessfully installed pygame on my Windows 10 computer, using Python3.6, here's my code :

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))
```

Python says the following :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Yann/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/Files/ProjetASINFO/lolol.py", line 2, in <module>
    from pygame.locals import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame.locals'
```

Have you any ideas about what could happen ? (My file isn't named pygame.py).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments stated, you might've installed a different old version of pygame, you will need to delete the old one and install the newest version from here and choose *pygame‑1.9.3‑cp36‑cp36m‑win32.whl*: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame

If it still does not work, check over your files and see if there's another `pygame.py` somewhere else in your $PATH. [Also, check out this post as it contains similar questions to yours.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21062062/6622817)